# blender export incorrect textures with .obj

Tags: texturing, export, obj

I'm a total beginner on blender and I recently tried to use textures.
Here is the object I apply the texture on.
[image: original object and texture]

When I export it as .obj file (associated with .mtl) and then import the new .obj file in blender, the texture map is incorrect.
It looks like the texture has been reset.
[image]
Am I exporting it wrong ?
Here are my export settings.
[image]

Comment: Check the Data Properties > UVmap panel ... probably there are two UV maps? If so you wold have to ad uv map node to specify what map should be used or delete the unwanted one.

Comment: The UV map panel shows only one UV map.

Comment: Please share your blend ... it should work like you did.